# Iron-Router randomly returning undefined in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

For some odd reason, `iron-router` randomly returns undefined.

```
this.route('pollyShow', {
    path: '/polly/:_id',
    template: 'polly_show',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
    before: function () {
        var id = this.params._id;
        var poll = Polls.findOne({_id: id});
        console.log(poll);
        var ip_array = poll.already_voted;
        $.getJSON("http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?", function(data){
            ip_voted = ip_array.indexOf(data.host);

            if (ip_voted > -1) {
                Router.go('pollyResults', {_id: id});
            }
        });
    },
    data: function() {

        return Polls.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
    }
});
```

Sometimes it is returning normally while other times it just returns undefined.

Is there any reason behind this?

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand: What is being returned as `undefined` here?

Comment: I mean `poll` is `undefined` in the console.log(poll); which is what is being returned under the `data : function () { .. }`

Comment: Using console.log I can see that it's actually undefined for some reason.

Comment: That is probably because the data from the subscription hasn't populated the `Polly` collection at the client yet. Set a `wait` on the subscription to `Polly` to ensure that it is `ready` before the route is processed.

Comment: I don't have any subscriptions set. How would I go about setting a wait?

Comment: So you are using `autopublish` package? If so, then move away from it and start using subscriptions. :)

Comment: Unless it was installed by default, I am not. I am simply just calling  the database right here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because the `Polly` collection is sometimes populated and at other times unpopulated when the route executes.

This problem can be prevented by explicitly [waiting on a `subscription`](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#waiting-on-subscriptions-waiton) using `waitOn` option in the route configuration.

---

From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#dataandsecurity):

> By default, a new Meteor app includes the autopublish and insecure packages, which together mimic the effect of each client having full read/write access to the server's database. These are useful prototyping tools, but typically not appropriate for production applications. When you're ready, just remove the packages.

To remove the packages, call `meteor remove <package-name>`.

Then you need to explicitly publish records which you want to see on the client on the server:

**server/publications.js**:

```
Meteor.publish('all_of_polly', function () { return Polls.find({}); });
```

And subscribe to it on the client:

```
this.route('pollyShow', {
    path: '/polly/:_id',
    template: 'polly_show',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
    waitOn: function () { return Meteor.subscribe('all_of_polly'); }
    // ...
});
```

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me, giving me an error in the console.

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Here is what i've got in code: http://pastebin.com/bdS2xYwE

Comment: You are defining your collection _after_ the route loads? They should be in a separate file which runs on both client and server. Also, it would help to know what was `undefined`.

Comment: the `route.js` file is neither in the client directory nor in the server directory. It's in the main directory of the app. As for what is said to be undefined is this line `Polls = new Meteor.collection('polls_all');` not sure what's wrong. I have this line above `Meteor.subscribe('polls_all');`

Comment: The error seems to be the capitalization of `Meteor.collection()` should be `Meteor.Collection()` that fixes an issue however the new error is `Exception from Deps recompute: Error: There is already a collection named 'polls_all'` 

This could probably be because I have the Meteor.subscribe in the waitOn and in the before methods however, I don't know how to access the collection in any other way. The collection itself is not correct either. I just have a meteor.collection object.

Comment: Ok, I understand, that autopublish is for prototyping (and for convenience)... But isn't there a method, which works with and without autopublish?

Comment: @pihentagy I am afraid what you are asking is not very clear here. I would recommend posting a proper question with what behavior you want. That would get more attention and is more likely to yield a solution.